# Pycryptodome: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _AES: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, importerror, pycryptodome

I have this problem when I try to import Pycryptodome.

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Python\Python 3.8\file.pyw", line 17, in <module> from Crypto.Cipher import AES File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pycrypto-2.6.1py3.8-win-amd64.egg\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 50, in <module> from Crypto.Cipher import _AES`

And then:

`ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _AES: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

I'm using Windows 64 bit with Python 64 bit 3.8.7. I installed Pycryptodome (version 3.9.9) with `pip install pycryptodome`. But when I tried to import AES from Pycryptodome, it errors out with the error above. Can anyone please tell me how to fix it? FYI, this is my first post on Stack Overflow, so if the post is missing anything, please tell me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh silly me, need to install pycryptodome 3.8.2. Dumb mistake lol.